Show that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{\Gamma(n)}{s^n}e^{-\frac{2a}{s}}{}_0F_1\left(n,\frac{a^2}{s^2}\right)\right\}(1)={}_0F_1\left(n,-a\right)^2$
I am trying to show that given $n, a > 0$
$$ G(s) =  \frac{\Gamma(n)}{s^n} e^{- \frac{2a}{s}} {}_0F_1 \left( n, \frac{a^2}{s^2} \right) $$
the inverse Laplace transform of $G$ evaluated at $t=1$ is
$$ g(1) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left\{ G \right\} (1) = {}_0F_1^2 \left( n, -a\right) $$
I have attempted to prove it by inverting the series expansion, but without success. Any help to show the following equality or finding a closed-form formula for the general inverse Laplace transform $g(t)$ would be much appreciated !

By trial and error, I found the inverse Laplace transform.  Given $g$, it is easy to prove this function corresponds to the Laplace inverse of $G$, by expressing it in terms of the square of a Bessel function of first kind, using the known relationship $z^{(n-1)/2}{}_0F_1(n,-z)=\Gamma(n)J_{n-1}(2\sqrt{z})$
$$
g(t)=t^{n-1}{}_0F_1^2(n,-at)=\frac{\Gamma^2(n)}{a^{n-1}}J_{n-1}^2(2\sqrt{at})
$$
The resulting Laplace transform is an integral that can be found in Gradshteyn (Table of Integrals, Series and Products - 8th Edition - p.705 - 6.615), which leads to the desired result once expressed in terms of a hypergeometric function
$$
G(s) = \int_0^\infty  e^{-st}  g(t) dt = \frac{\Gamma^2(n)}{a^{n-1}s}e^{-\frac{2a}{s}}I_{n-1}\left(\frac{2a}{s}\right) = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{s^n}e^{-\frac{2a}{s}}{}_0F_1\left(n,\frac{a^2}{s^2}\right)
$$
